# database eror localhost

Tags: mariadb, linux, xampp

ask for a solution xampp linux error like this?

Error    : The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist
error    : Corrupt
Phase 4/7: Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'

-ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 8: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 17: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist
ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 60: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 69: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 87: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 173: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 182: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 184: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 195: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 200: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 203: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 327: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 330: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 398: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 403: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 405: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 408: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 412: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 417: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 438: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist

ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 446: The user specified as a definer ('mariadb.sys'@'localhost') does not exist
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the user and try the upgrade again:

```
CREATE USER `mariadb.sys`@`localhost` ACCOUNT LOCK PASSWORD EXPIRE;

GRANT SELECT, DELETE ON `mysql`.`global_priv` TO `mariadb.sys`@`localhost`;
```